# Same CSS, selectors and images but different height?

Tags: html, css

I have a really weird issue thats seen in Safari and Chrome. Somehow it works just fine in Firefox.

Look at this URL in one of the above browsers: https://musik.dk/therollingstones/videoer

If you scroll down, you'll notice a videothumb that floats very different than the rest. The "sinner" is the video starting with the name "Arrive in Japan" thats just a single pixel height than the rest.

I've looked into the inspector, but everything is exact as heigh and wide as all others (its the same template) and the image is 100% the same height and width. It could be a render issue, but its the same video all the time.

Can anyone figure that out?

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: They look fine to me on Chrome. Mind post a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Yes, looks fine to me as well in Safari on Mac - images all the same dimensions as well.

Comment: i have tried every browser i know, and cant replicate the problem, can you give a screenshot?  Also, what versions of the browsers are you using?

Comment: +what OS are you using?

Comment: Updated with screenshot!

Comment: @SamDenton OSX. BUt tested on a similar system and it was not shown. Think maybe its only an issue when viewed on bigger screens although the contentarea width are the same

Comment: The page is pretty much blank for me.

Comment: Ahh sorry DB is been moved right now, so for the next 15 min it can be blank. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The floated article in question is "snagging" on the article to the left above it, which is slightly taller than the others. That's the problem with floating.

My advice would be to remove all of the `float: left;` declarations (there are two for desktop and various instances within media queries as well) and use `display: inline-block` instead, perhaps with a reduced right margin of, say, 0.5% (although these get a bit inaccurate).

Instead of right margins, you could apply `text-align: justify` to the container of all those articles. That will only mess up the last row if there aren't 4 articles, but that's fixable, too.

Or you could use flexbox, which is the modern way to do this, though not fully supported across the board yet.

Comment: How would you make it in flexbox? We dont support IE8 so it would be a possibility, although we need the old flexbox-model for IE9

Comment: Personally, I think flexbox is too new, especially if you need to support older IEs. Using old syntax sounds too messy to me. This is where `inline-block` comes in really handy, and is my go-to in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to that video having japanese characters in the name. For whatever reason, they render slightly larger, making the `.ellipsis` box 1px larger.

As mentioned by ralph.m I would make then display:inline-block; and remove the float, then set `margin-right: 23.8%;`

Comment: Do you mean then video-class? It seems I can actually remove the floets without any issue, so this is already done. However I'm not sure what you mean regarding the margin-right? It would cause huge gaps unless I did misunderstand it